# Entity Framework foreign key object name change

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have an annoying problem that i can't seem to solve. Lets say i have a database with two tables.

```
Student
INT Id
NVARCHAR(30) Name
INT PrimaryTeacherId
INT SecondaryTeacherId

Teacher
INT Id
NVARCHAR(30) Name
```

Now when i set foreign key for PrimaryTeacherId and SecondaryTeacherId and use DatabaseFirst mapping in my project i get something like this for Student table

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryTeacherId { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryTeacherId { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Teacher1 { get; set; }
}
```

Note the virtual part of the class and their names, Teacher and Teacher1. No matter how i call my FKs entity framework will just override it and set increment names. That's ok if i have one or two keys to the same table but when there is more it's easy to get lost and code looks kinda annoying having object names with numbers in them. I know i can change generated classes name in my solution but when i update model changes will be lost. I'm also using Metadata partial classes for generated classes (mostly for validation and display attributes), can i change name there maybe?

**TLDR:** I would like to have Teacher and Teacher1 have custom names, so something like this would be awesome

```
public partial class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryTeacherId { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryTeacherId { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher PrimaryTeacher { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher SecondaryTeacher { get; set; }
}
```